# Twig - An asset contains a path

Tags: symfony, path, twig, assets

I am working on a page that display videos 
so this is my code:

And I want to concatenate an URL to a path in an asset:

```html
<video src="{{asset('bundles/cdlrcode/videos/'+'{{ path('coursvideo_edit', { 'id': entity.id }) }}'')}}" controls>                </tr>
```

Comment: Did you tried `~` instead of `+`?

Answer (score 1):

Strings in twig are concatenated by `~`

So, path to video should be

```
{{ asset('bundles/cdlrcode/videos/' ~ path('coursvideo_edit', { 'id': entity.id } )) }}
```

Comment: thank you , the concatenation has worked but i had this error In the same line ..
 
Arguments must be separated by a comma. Unexpected token "name" of value "coursvideo_edit" ("punctuation" expected with value ",") in CdlrcodeBundle:CoursVideo:show.html.twig at line 15

Comment: `{{ path ... }}` shouldn't be quoted. Also there is one trailing extra quote.

Comment: another error in the same line  .. A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{" in CdlrcodeBundle:CoursVideo:show.html.twig at line 15

Comment: Almost - remove the `{{ }}` around the path call.